# Setting up an ATtiny45 as I2C master - SCL toggles low, but refuses to toggle high

Tags: c, i2c, attiny, troubleshooting

Another pin, another question: However closely related to [Setting up an ATtiny45 as I2C master - SDA stuck low](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58944/setting-up-an-attiny45-as-i2c-master-sda-stuck-low) this is different question.

I'm trying to control a DAC from an ATtiny45, but somehow the SCL line **gets stuck after toggled once**. To find the problem in the code I did the following:

- I simplified the circuit to only the controller with the pull up resistors, there is no I2C slave attached;
- I simplified the C code base to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.

The following is the result so far:

- When I remove the toggle'ing from the main loop, the SCL line is high;
- When I include the SCL toggle-code: After first toggle, the SCL line is low;
- The heartbeat pin proves that the main loop is active.

What happens:

- After the first time I write to USITC-bit in USICR, SCL is toggled low, after that it is stuck low.

> **USITC** Universal Serial Interface Toggle Clock Port Pin
>
> **USICR** Universal Serial Interface Control Register
>
> **SCL**   I2C Serial Clock pin

What I expect:

- Every time I write to USITC-bit in USICR, I expect SCL to toggle up or down (in the same rythm as the heartbeat pin).

> Writing a one to this bit location toggles the USCK/SCL value either
>   from 0 to 1, or from 1 to 0. The toggling is independent of the
>   setting in the Data Direction Register, but if the PORT value is to be
>   shown on the pin the corresponding DDR pin must be set as output (to
>   one). This feature allows easy clock generation when implementing
>   master devices.

**My question is:** What am I doing wrong, how can I make SCL follow USITC toggle'ing?

Chapter 15 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2586.pdf) is about the Universal Serial Interface and I'm trying to set up I2C/TWI as described in 15.3.4 and further.

Here is the minimized program code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define _BS(bit) ( 1 << ( bit ) )
#define _BC(bit) ( 0 << ( bit ) )

const uint8_t heartbeatPin      = PB3;
const uint8_t sdaPin            = PB0;
const uint8_t sclPin            = PB2;

const uint8_t maskUSICR =                                       // Universal Serial Interface Control Register
                                _BC( USISIE ) |                 // (rw) disable USI Start Condition Interrupt Enable
                                _BC( USIOIE ) |                 // (rw) disable USI Counter Overflow Interrupt Enable
                                _BS( USIWM1 ) | _BC( USIWM0 ) | // (rw) Two wire mode, not using counter overflow
                                _BC( USICS1 ) | _BC( USICS0 ) | // (rw) Clock select => software clock strobe (USICLK)
                                _BC( USICLK ) |                 // (-w) Clock strobe
                                _BC( USITC );                   // (-w) Toggle Port Pin

/*
        ATtiny45

        pin     1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
        name    PB5     PB3     PB4     GND     PB0     PB1     PB2     VCC
        func    !RESET  h/beat          GND     SDA             SCL     VCC
*/

int main( void ) {
        //
        // Setup
        //

        // Setting up output drivers
        DDRB =                                                  // Port B Data Direction Register.
                _BS( heartbeatPin ) |                           // PB3 output driver enable
                _BS( sdaPin ) |                                 // SDA output driver enable
                _BS( sclPin );                                  // SCL output driver enable

        // Enable SCL & SDA
        PORTB |=                                                // PORT B output register
                _BS( sclPin ) |                                 // Set SCL pin high
                _BS( sdaPin );                                  // Set SDA pin high

        // Set up I2C / TWI
        USICR =                                                 // Universal Serial Interface Control Register
                maskUSICR;                                      // I2C, no interrupts, software clock

        //
        // Endless loop
        //
        while ( 1 ) {
                // Toggle SCL high
                USICR = maskUSICR |                                     // Universal Serial Interface Control Register
                        _BS( USITC );                                   // Release SCL, Toggle Clock Port Pin

                // Toggle hearbeat Pin
                PINB = _BS( heartbeatPin );                             // Toggle heartbeat pin
        }
}
```

Comment: So you're bit-banging I2C, right? Did you know AVR-GCC has a macro _BV that is exactly the same as your _BS macro, and also your _BC macro is *always* zero?

Comment: Not exactly. I use the USI hardware for I2C/TWI, but it still requires the CPU to do fair bit of work.

Comment: @vicatcu I am aware of BV and BC. The reason for BC and BS is that I can use it to make the code more verbose when setting/clearing several bits in a single hardware register. As you may notice the definition for `maskUSICR` is exactly 8 bits regardless of some bits being set to 0.

Comment: @jippie... maskUSICR is exactly zero, not just some of the bits, maybe that's what you intended though

Comment: I disagree. According to the disassembly of the code: `3a:   80 e2           ldi     r24, 0x20       ; 32` `3c:   8d b9           out     USICR, r24      ; 0x0d` it is 32 (decimal).

Comment: I'm just looking at the code you've pasted in the question... _BC(bit) ( 0 << ( bit ) ) always evaluates to zero... and you assign maskUSICR nothing but a combination of _BC(x) values OR'd together... so maskUSICR must also be zero.

Comment: @vicatcu look closer, there are couple of _BS's there too. Funny to see BTW that Atmel use more or less the same method to set register values.

Comment: crazy, must have been an optical illusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the pin toggle up and down, I changed the main loop with a write to USISR as follows:

```
    while ( 1 ) {
            // Toggle SCL low
            USICR = maskUSICR |                                     // Universal Serial Interface Control Register
                    _BS( USITC );                                   // Release SCL, Toggle Clock Port Pin

            USISR   =                                               // SCL is released by setting correct status bits
                    _BS( USISIF ) |
                    _BS( USIOIF ) |
                    _BS( USIPF )  |
                    _BS( USIDC )  |
                    _BC( USICNT0 );

            // Toggle hearbeat Pin
            PINB = _BS( heartbeatPin );                             // Toggle heartbeat pin
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatically correct way to set a bit in AVR-GCC is: `value |= _BV(bit_number)`. Likewise to clear a bit it's: `value &= ~_BV(bit_number)`...

Have you taken a look at [Atmel App Note AVR310: Using the USI module as a I2C master](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2561.pdf)? Here's [a link](http://www.atmel.com/Images/AVR310.zip) to accompanying software.

Comment: Was not aware of the App Note. However it features 'C-code driver for TWI master', I don't see a single line of code quickly browsing the document. I'll Google for that in the morning.

Comment: @jippie I added a link to the software... you can find these by going to the atmel website, going under Design Support, choosing Application notes, and searching there

Comment: The disadvantage of using prefab code is the lower educational value of copy/paste, but I might be able to use it to pinpoint my error.

Comment: @jippie by all means you should read and understand the code prior to using it :-)